# Is the select() wrapper in IO::Select thread-safe? How to work around?

Tags: perl, sockets, network-programming, nonblocking

Let's say I have a thread:

```
sub     new {
        my      $class = shift;
        my      $self = ref $class || $class;

        bless { 'read_set'  => IO::Select->new,
                'write_set' => IO::Select->new,
                'error_set' => IO::Select->new }, $self;
}


sub     start {
        my      $self = shift;

        $self->{'thread'} = threads->create(\&worker_thr, $self);
        $self->{'thread'}->detach;
}

sub     worker_thr {
         my      $self = shift;

         while(1) {
                 my($read_active, $write_active, $error_active) = 
                    IO::Select->select(
                            $self->{'read_set'},
                            $self->{'write_set'},
                            $self->{'error_set'}, 
                            undef
                    );
         }

}
```

Since I have provided no timeout to `select()` and it blocks indefinitely until activity is detected on one of the descriptor (well, "handle") sets, what happens if another thread modifies the contents of the sets (e.g. adds a new socket for polling)?

Is it implemented in a thread-safe manner, relative to the Perl POSIX threads implementation?

If not, I suppose I can stick the blocking `select()` call in a block with its own scope and lock the sets or, more cleanly, the entire package data.   What is the best way to wake `select()` up to return, from another thread so that the contents of the sets can be manipulated?  Thread-specific signal?  Semaphore?  Suggestions welcome.

Thanks muchly!

**Edit:** Well, thread-specific "signal" is out.  As explained here ( http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html ): "Correspondingly, sending a signal to a thread does not disrupt the operation the thread is currently working on: The signal will be acted upon after the current operation has completed. For instance, if the thread is stuck on an I/O call, sending it a signal will not cause the I/O call to be interrupted such that the signal is acted up immediately."

That still leaves me wondering how I should handle the issue of waking `select()` up in a thread if I want it to block indefinitely instead of returning after a fixed timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, perl threads don't share any data, so if one thread changes its sets it will not affect the other. So yes, it is thread-safe, but it probably doesn't do what you want it to do.

If you really want to wake-up another thread or process that's blocking on a select, an easy solution is to add a pipe to it's read queue. You can then wake it up by writing a byte to that pipe.